# Detect timeout in Ant exec task

Tags: java, android, ant

When you set the timeout attribute in the Ant exec task and the task times out the process, is there a way to detect the timeout? I don't see anything useful in my result, output, or error properties that would indicate a timeout.

Answer (score 3):

When [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) kills a subprocess due to a timeout, the parent Ant process logs the message `Timeout: killed the sub-process`. However, since the `<exec>` redirector only captures output from the subprocess, there is no indication of the timeout in the `<exec>` `outputProperty` or `errorProperty`.

To set a property indicating the subprocess timed out, Ant's log output can be captured using the [`<record>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html) task as demonstrated in the following example.

```
<target name="exec-timeout">
  <record name="exec.log" action="start" />
    <exec executable="java" timeout="1500">
      <arg line="-jar /path/to/executable.jar" />
    </exec>
  <record name="exec.log" action="stop" />      

  <condition property="timed-out" else="false">
    <resourcecontains resource="exec.log"
        substring="Timeout: killed the sub-process" />
  </condition>
  <delete file="exec.log" />

  <echo message="exec timed out: ${timed-out}" />
</target>
```

#### Output

```
exec-timeout:
     [exec] Timeout: killed the sub-process
     [exec] Result: 143
     [echo] exec timed out: true

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```